Antología del Comic Español
I'm currently improving my Spanish from basic to a more decent written and spoken level.
The way this process works for me is reading comics and easy books in the beginning. I don't trust myself to pick one specific comic or book for this task, so that's why I wanted to hear from you, what are the current ( or maybe traditional ) popular comics from Spain?
Thanks and Saludos,
Tomas

Probably the question is going to be closed because it's opinion-based and out-of-topic according to the site definition. In any case I would recommend you Superlópez by Jan - the first ten issues -, Paracuellos by Carlos Giménez and any book by Paco Roca - you can start from "Los Surcos del Azar". :-)

And let's not forget "La Balada del Norte" by Zapico ... Here you can find a list obtained from a poll made in a Spanish magazine https://www.whakoom.com/goscinny/lists/100_mejores_comics_espanoles_segun_votacion_rockdeluxe_46362

Thanks @RubioRic !

You must try "Mortadelo y Filemón" by Francisco Ibañez.
